# Gradle libraries have different version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Last night, I did two things with my android code and now it does no longer work.

The two things I did was:

- Add my first adview with the corresponding gradle implementation
- Update Android Studio to the latest version (3.1.1)

Now the app can not build because of version mixing in the library versions. My gradle tells me that on the lines

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

I have no idea on how to fix this and nothing I search for gives me the answer on what to do. Is there a way to auto-generate the needed gradle for my app, or could anyone please point me in the direction of were to start when fixing this?

Thanks beforehand, my gradle dependencies are below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Please add the output of  `gradlew dependencies` to your question for better analysis.

Answer (score 0):

just try this one ,

```
"com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1"
```

reference link

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v14-preference